# How to split a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I've been trying to create a function that would take **one string**
and do this with it -
if the string submitted is "HelloWorld:GoodbyeWorld" the function would create an array and the contents would be HelloWorld and GoodbyeWorld, so
( "HelloWorld", "GoodbyeWorld" ). This is my code.

```
function parseBadges($str) {
    $realstr=$str;
    $badges = array();
    while(strpos($realstr, ':') !== false) {
        array_push($badges, substr(0, strpos($realstr,':')));
        $realstr = substr(0, strpos($realstr, ':'));
    }
    return badges;
}
```

Trying var_dump(parseBadges("FavoerDoer:")); returns

```
array(1) { [0]=> bool(false) }
```

No clue why this is happening, any ideas?

Comment: For example if you do parseBadges('abc1:abc2:abc3:') it should return an array with ( "abc1","abc2","abc3" )

Comment: Just to let you know that the answer you accepted, despite the good explanation, doesn't work on `abc1:abc2:abc3:` last match will be blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not work because you are doing an easy task in a complicate way.
Please consider:

```
function parse_badges($str) {
    return (is_string($str))?explode(':',$str):false;
}
```

Explanation:

1. The function expects a string => `$str`.
2. If the passed variable is not a string it returns false => `(is_string)? ... :false;`
3. If its a string `explode()` will split your string on the character you chosen and return an array containing the sub-strings.

More reading: [PHP explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

**Edit**

If you want to avoid empty results like in `word1:word2:` that will return an array of 3 that the last cell will be empty. We can simply add `array_filter()`:

```
function parse_badges($str) {
    return (is_string($str))?array_filter(explode(':',$str)):false;
}
```

The `array_filter` will remove by default the empty cells.

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe PHP has a function for it. Gonna mark as answer in 5 mins

Comment: Actually its common. In JS its called `split()` in PHP the negative of `explode()` is `implode()`. Have fun!

Comment: Good explanation, but it doesn't work on this `HelloWorld:GoodbyeWorld:HiThere:`

Comment: it does - it return an empty at the end let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str= "HelloWorld:GoodbyeWorld:HiThere:";

function parseBadges($str) {
    return preg_split('/:/i', $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}

print_r(parseBadges($str));
```

Output:

```
(
    [0] => HelloWorld
    [1] => GoodbyeWorld
    [2] => HiThere
)
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/NjlY3j)

Comment: Correct - but for such an easy task why turn to regex - There is a performance cost : [explode vs preg_split](http://micro-optimization.com/explode-vs-preg_split.html)

Comment: @ShlomiHassid If you need to check for `if(EMPTY($string)` there will be a performance cost also.

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseBadges($str)
    if(strpos($str, ':') !== false) 
        $badges = explode(':', $str);
        return $badges;
    }

    return false;
}
print_r($badges);
```