# How to Separate each line of a file with a comma in laravel or php?

Tags: php, laravel

Please i have a list of contacts which i want to separate each line with a comma when reading from my application. I have tried various ways but not working. I need help.
This is how it looks but i want to separate each line with a ***comma***

[image]

This is my Controller file

```
public function bulk_sms(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request,[
            'contacts' => 'required',

          ]);

        $upload = $request->file('contacts');
        $filePath = $upload->getRealPath();

        $file = fopen($filePath, 'r');
        $readcontacts = stream_get_line($file , filesize($filePath), ",");
        return $readcontacts;
        fclose($file);


    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711105/how-to-split-a-string-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can replace the trailing `\n` in each line by `,` like this example

```
$text = "";

while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
    $text .= str_replace("\n", ",", $line);
}
```

last thing you will need to remove the trailing `,`

```
$text = rtrim($text, ",");
```

Comment: Hey Mahmoud Abdelgawad, Thanks for the Support.